# Google Sheets: Conditionally Shade an Individual Set of Repeating Groups of Cells Based on Value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet I use to document my quotes for customers. I've copied and pasted it down the sheet several times. Within each quote is a list validated field where the options are "Won" or "Lost." When I select "Won," I want to turn that background color of JUST that quote green. However, I also only want to shade green the fields that I am not entering text into or accomplishing the calculations on (the data fields); I want to shade the background of the "form" and the "labels." (See screenshot where I did this by hand.)

I've attempted do this myself, but I'm having two issues.

1. I have to create separate conditional format rules for each quote/group of cells. This is tedious. I'd like, if possible, to create one rule that is able to adapt the conditional test of ="Won" to each group/quote separately.
2. I have to individually select each and every cell to be highlighted because if I just do A1:G33, all of the cells change color, even the ones in black and gray. I know this is expected, but is there a way around it?

I'm confused why applying the rule to the first group and copying and pasting it doesn't work. All of the quotes change green if the first quote shows "Won." This functionality works correctly with the built-in conditions that test the value of the cell itself. However, custom formulas to test the value of another cell don't "repeat" and operate individually it seems.

[image: Example of Correct Quote Shading for a "Won" Quote]

EDIT: Link to spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OH16NXLiRzY3-EdZaxmUl5Vp6cQNPzY-_-LV7VIDl8U/edit#gid=983650786

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Here you go...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OH16NXLiRzY3-EdZaxmUl5Vp6cQNPzY-_-LV7VIDl8U/edit#gid=983650786

Answer (score 0):

in your case perhaps best would be to color the first table exactly as you wish and then select it, copy it, select the first cell of the next table and:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, Player0. That is a possibility, but unfortunately, that's not the solution I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Apps Script

This way you can have a lot of flexibility and its easier to manage.

You seem to already have an `onEdit` trigger, so you could integrate some more logic into that to test for statues. I can't implement everything you want but this should get you well on the way.

```js
function onEdit(e){
  // Getting the information on the edited cell
  let editedCell = e.range;
  let sheet = editedCell.getSheet()
  
  // If the edited cell is in column 6, in "Quotes" and is value "Won"
  if (editedCell.getColumn() == 6 && sheet.getName() == "Quotes" && editedCell.getValue() == "Won") {
    // Get the row to know where to change the format
    let statusRow = editedCell.getRow();
    // Get the range of the whole form
    let formRange = sheet.getRange(statusRow, 3, 17, 6)
    // Set the background color
    formRange.setBackground("green")
  }
}
```

[image]

Hopefully you can see how you might extend this to include other ranges. You would need to base everything of the position of the edited cell. I have identified it by its column, the sheet that contains it, and its value. You can extend this to include checks on the value next to it for example. Then to change the color of each black box, you would need to define a range for each, relative to the edited cell.

#### References

- [setBackgroundColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)
- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: Thanks! I think I can tinker with this example enough to make it work for my needs.